# UISlider view problem

Tags: xcode, view, makefile, slider

I am trying to make a UISlider/slider but I do not know why it is giving problems. Here is the snippet:

.h =

```
@interface sliderViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;

}

@property (nonatomic) float Value;
@property (nonatomic) float minimumValue;
@property (nonatomic) float maximumValue;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isContinuous) BOOL continuous;
```

@end

.m =

```
@implementation sliderViewController
@synthesize minimumValue;
@synthesize maximumValue;
@synthesize Value;
@synthesize continuous;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 60, 200, 30);
    mySlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [mySlider addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(sliderValueChanges) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    mySlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mySlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    mySlider.maximumValue = 10.0;
    mySlider.continuous = YES;
    mySlider.value = 5.0;
    [theView addSubview: mySlider];

}

- (void)sliderValueChanges:(id)sender{
    UISlider *slider = sender;
    if (mySlider==slider) {
        printf("Value of slider is %f\n", [mySlider value]);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: What kind of problems are you seeing? Crash? Compilation?

There could be several issues with your code, but you haven't told us what problem you are seeing. So we need a little more detail. :-)

Comment: e.g. if i change  mySlider.value  to  10 insted of 5, and when i try it. the value still is 5

Comment: ps.    [theView addSubview: mySlider]; dont work too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a `UISlider` object as an `IBOutlet` implies that you will connect that ivar to a `UISlider` in your interface via Interface Builder. Did you do that? If not, that would certainly explain why changing the slider value in the UI doesn't actually do anything.

Also, when you connect an `IBOutlet` ivar to a matching UI element in Interface Builder, there is no need then to create the object in your your code. It is already "created" by virtue of being defined in your NIB file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you are calling this method (sliderValueChanges). Rather than calling it like that please call it like (sliderValueChanges:).It works fine!